# calling a parameterized function in a preparedstatement

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am attempting to use a jdbc preparedstatement to insert data into a sql server 2008 database.  The difficulty I'm running into is that I have point-in-time IDs which are subject to change, and I need to look up the constant ID based on other elements of the insert.  I have written a stored function to perform the lookup, myIDLookup(x,y).

I tried writing a preparedstatement like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (id,idElement1,idElement2,otherItem) 
VALUES (myIDLookup(?,?),?,?,?)
```

I have seen examples successfully using built in functions such as now(), but haven't seen anything about using parameterized functions in a preparedstatement.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try creating  and calling such preparedstatment?

Comment: Yes, it did not seem to see the 2 parameters in the function call.  So it threw off the indices of all of my other parameters, causing some parsing errors.

Comment: As far as I know this should work. What error do you get?

Answer (score 3):

I think the right way of doing this is to write a stored proc to insert rows that takes x and y and generates the id by calling myIDLookup ad then inserts the row too. A template may look like :

```
stored proc insertRow (x, y, z)
{
   id = myIDLookup(x , y)
   insert into table values (id, x , y, z)
}
```